# Page numbering preface

Tags: numbering

I was wondering if there is a way to make a page start numbering with 2 instead of one. (my dedication page is starting at 1 and I want it to start with 2, so counting the title page as 1 but not showing a number).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, left=1.25in, bottom=1.75in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
{0pt}{15pt}{15pt}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{Table of contents}}}

\graphicspath{{C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Seattle University/Documents/Latex/Dissertation/Figures}}
    
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
    [#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
    {#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}
\newlength{\bracewidth}

\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{\settowidth{\bracewidth}{$#1$}#1\hspace*{-1\bracewidth}\smash{\underbrace{\makebox{\phantom{$#1$}}}_{#2}}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % dots after chapter entries
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{8em} % increase space for chapter numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % put this before chapter numbers

 


\begin{document}
        
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \input{title}
        
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \input{Dedication}
    
    \input{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \listoftables
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    \input{Chapter_1}
    
    \input{Chapter_2}
    
    \input{Chapter_3}
    
    \input{Chapter_4}
    
    \input{Chapter_5}
    
    \input{Chapter_6}
        
    \input{Appendix}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `\setcounter{page}{2}` to set the page counter to 2 starting from the current page (place this macro right before you include the dedication page, for example). Note that your code is not compilable for people here on this site, because it includes several files that only you know the contents of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pagenumbering{roman}` both resets the page number to `1` and also changes the formatting (to roman). So just do

```
\pagenumbering{roman}%
\stepcounter{page}% Change page to page + 1 (which is 2 in this case)
```

Or, if you want some general page number `<num>`, use

```
\pagenumbering{roman}%
\setcounter{page}{<num>}%
```